# Simulate clicking a link when scraping with Python and BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, redirect, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, mechanize

After reading for years, this is my first SO question. Thanks in advance for the help!

I'm looking to scrape content from articles on the Forbes website. The this as an example page: http://www.forbes.com/sites/katevinton/2015/09/22/google-microsoft-qualcomm-and-baidu-announce-joint-investment-cloudflare/. When an article is loaded directly, the page source becomes a mess of JavaScript that is hard to parse. However, when I click on the 'print' button, it appends a "/print/" to the URL and gives me a page I have no problem parsing with BeautifulSoup.

When I enter the url with "/print/" appended, it redirects to the non-"/print/" page. I only get to the actual "/print/" page when I click on the button. Thus, my question is: how can I simulate clicking that print button programmatically to get to the Beautiful Soup scrapable page? Poking around, people seem to recommend mechanize for simulating browser actions but I'm not sure what I'd be trying to do with it in this case. Or is there a better way to scrape this data entirely?

I appreciate any help you can offer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to request it with the referer set, so something like this would work:

```
import requests

url = "http://www.forbes.com/sites/samsungbusiness/2015/09/23/how-your-car-is-becoming-the-next-hot-tech-gadget/print/"
print requests.get(url, headers={"referer": url.replace("print/", "")}).content
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much. That did the trick. So that I can be more self-sufficient in the future, how did you know it would be looking for the prior page's referer? Was it just obvious from the page's behavior, or was it in the page's code somewhere?

Comment: I didn't know, it was an educated guess, I do a lot of web scraping. There are only so many differences that could have caused it, and referer is the most obvious choice in this case. That it redirects back is a good indicator, it is probably to prevent people direct linking the /print page, which has no ads, so they check if the user came from the article. The major reasons that a page behaves different in scripts vs. browsers are: javascript, custom headers and CSRF tokens (Only POST). I always start by emulating the headers of the real browser request, that's usually the best first step.